# Haskell: Segmentation Fault using big CSV file and Cassava

Tags: csv, haskell

I am trying to use cassava with 2 large CSV files. The code compiles, but just gives 'Segmentation Fault' when I run it. Here is the full code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Control.Applicative
import qualified Data.ByteString.Internal
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Search as BLS
import Data.Csv
import Data.Char
import qualified Data.Vector as V

lang1 :: String
lang1 = "eng"

pattern :: Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString
pattern = ""

checkIfLang :: String -> Bool
checkIfLang x =
if x == lang1
    then True
    else False

myOptions = defaultDecodeOptions {
  decDelimiter = fromIntegral (ord '\t')
}

main :: IO ()
main = do
sentenceCSV <- BL.readFile "sentenceData/sentences.csv"
linksCSV <- BL.readFile "sentenceData/links.csv"
case decodeWith myOptions NoHeader (BLS.replace "\"" pattern sentenceCSV) of
    Left err -> putStrLn err
    Right v -> V.forM_ v $ \ (id :: Int, lang :: String, sentence :: String) ->
        if checkIfLang lang
          then do putStrLn $ show id ++ " has lang of " ++ lang ++ "and is:"
                  putStrLn $ sentence
          else return ()
```

I am unsure what to do, since I can't figure out how to do it from just googling. Any corrections, even if not related to my problem, will help me a lot in learning Haskell. I am extremely new to it.

Comment: `if x then True else False` better written as `x`.

Comment: `when x y = if x then y else return ()`. https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Debugging/CompiledCode might let you figure out which of your dependencies causes this, so you can file an issue on their github.

Comment: How large is your "large CSV"? Check if your program is simply allocating too much, using some resource monitor.

Comment: You could try shrinking your input files until the problem goes away to find a minimal example, then remove code as long as that doesn't get rid of the segfault, and so on. In particular, if you manage to only directly use Cassava's code and still get a segfault, you can go to their github immediately. (afaik segfaults in Haskell imply you used Unsafe modules or it's somebody elses problem, corollary: it doesn't happen whenever one allocates too much)

Comment: @ago I reduced the size of the files and it works now, so what can I do to make the bigger files work? Do I allocate more memory to the program, and how would I do that?

Comment: The program should arguably be able to allocate memory as it requires it. However, there are options to control its mechanisms more granularly documented here: http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc//8.2.2/docs/html/users_guide/runtime_control.html#rts-options-to-control-the-garbage-collector

Comment: @RyanFord btw can you provide an indication of what size file started with that caused this problem? I'd like to see if it can be reproduced...